# Array elements vs properties?

Tags: javascript

So to follow up a previous question;

Due to the dynamic functionality of using properties and iterating with

```
for(var key in array)
```

I've used this quite a lot in favor of trying to enumerate an array and iterating by numbers.

What are the pro's and cons of just .pushing elements and setting as properties instead?

Apart from the obvious identification differences that is.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848

Comment: Well, I get a JSON which has 4 levels, so to contain that data and be able to handle it without knowing any values, I went with properties instead and let it handle itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important difference is that enumerating will list all properties, even those in the prototype chain. For instance (and this is not uncommon btw):

```
Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.length == 0;
}

var myArray = [2, 3, 5];

for(var key in myArray) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

will list

```
0
1
2
isEmpty
```

The `isEmpty` is most likely not what you want in that enumeration.

Also, the `length` property is only affected by numeric indexes. It is not relevant in this case, since you are enumerating elements, but something to keep in mind.

```
var a = [];

a["4"] = "test";
a.length; // 5

a[10] = "ing";
a.length = 11;
```

Comment: Well, assume no prototyping, I just use them as an array to handle data, nothing else.

Comment: The prototyping may not necessarily come from your own scripts. A third party script or plugin may add those, which effectively means that either you write all JavaScript exclusively yourselves, or forever remain vigilant when you do use others scripts.

Answer (score 7):

**To make it short**:
**NEVER** use `for in` on arrays, its extremely slow and prone to failure.

#### Explanation

Well, although the `Array` in JavaScript is an `Object`, there's no good reason to use the `for in` loop in order to iterate over it. In fact there a number of very good reasons **against** the use of `for in` on an `Array`.

While it may seem like a good choice at first, to trade the some speed against the readability of the `for in` construct, this has **major** implications on performance.

The `for in` does in fact iterate over the indexes of an `Array`. But it does also traverse the prototype chain. So one already has to use `hasOwnProperty` in order to make sure to filter out unwanted properties, and still if any additional properties happen to be defined on the array, they will still make it through this filter.

```
Array.prototype.bar = 1; // poisoning the Object.prototype, NEVER do this
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
for(var i in foo) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

The above code results in "indexes" `0`, `1`, `2` **and** `bar` being printed out.

**Using hasOwnProperty for filtering**

```
Array.prototype.bar = 1; // poisoning the Object.prototype, NEVER do this
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
foo.blub = 2;
for(var i in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

The above code results now prints the"indexes" `0`, `1`, `2` **and** `blub`, you cannot filter out the `blub` in any meaningful way unless you validate the key being an positive integer.

**Performance**

Now, combining the already slow nature of the prototype traversing `for in` with the use of `hasOwnProperty` results in a performance degradation of a factor of up to **20x**.

So if you want to iterate over an `Array` in JavaScript, **always** use the classic `for` loop construct.

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...... 100000000];
for(var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(list[i]);
}
```

As you can see, there's one extra catch in the above example. That is the caching of the length via `l = list.length`.

While the `length` property is defined on the array itself, there's still an overhead for doing the lookup on each iteration. And while recent JavaScript engines **may** apply optimization in this case, one can never be sure that those optimizations are actually in place, nor can one be sure whether they reach the speed of the above caching. In fact leaving out the caching may result in a performance degradation of a factor of up to **2x** (and even more in older engines).